# Change the tab color of excel sheets using ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, excel

I need to change the tab color of excel sheets with a particular color...something like this using ruby scripting[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an equivalent Ruby code using stdlib [`WIN32OLE`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) :

```
require 'win32ole'

# create an instance of the Excel application object
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
# make Excel visible
excel.visible = true
# open the excel from the desired path
wb = excel.workbooks.open("C:\\Users\\test.xlsx")

#iterate through each worksheet and color the tab as you want
1.upto(3).each do |i|
  # getting the worksheet
  wbs = wb.worksheets(i)
  #color it
  wbs.tab.color = 255
end
```

*output*

[image: tab color]

Look documentation of [`Tab.Color property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.tab.color%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [`Worksheet.Tab Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.tab.aspx).